# How Cuda compilation process takes place?

Tags: compilation, cuda, nvcc, ptx

According to NVIDIAs Programming Guide:

> Source files for CUDA applications consist of a mixture of
> conventional C++ host code, plus GPU device functions. The CUDA
> compilation trajectory separates the device functions from the host
> code, compiles the device functions using the proprietary NVIDIA
> compilers and assembler, compiles the host code using a C++ host
> compiler that is available, and afterwards embeds the compiled GPU
> functions as fatbinary images in the host object file. In the linking
> stage, specific CUDA runtime libraries are added for supporting remote
> SPMD procedure calling and for providing explicit GPU manipulation
> such as allocation of GPU memory buffers and host-GPU data transfer.

- What does *using the proprietary NVIDIA compilers and assembler* mean?
- Also, what is a PTX and a cubin file? and in which step of compilation do these take place?

   I have searched a lot about this concept but, i would like a simple explanation

Answer (score 1):

The nvcc documentation explains the different compilation steps and their respective compilers. https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#cuda-compilation-trajectory

Cubin files contain the "real" sass assembler code, whereas ptx files contain assembler code for a "virtual" GPU architecture.

[image: CUDA compilation trajectory]